# Webapplication returns "white" jsp pages

Tags: jsp, caching, proxy

I have problems with web pages that become "white".
The system is designed so that System A has an iframe to (`iframe src="https://....`) system B.
System B is an session bases struts web application.

The system architecture looks like this:

> load balancers -> System A(iframe system B) -> load balancer ->
>   Apache proxy -> System B (Tomcat)

There are web pages in system B (the one that gets iframed) which sometimes becomes white for some customers.

What I have observed is that the http calls from the iframe in system A against application B does not reach the web server when the pages gets white (I have checked the web server log).

**What could cause this problem?**

First I thought it was a caching problem, but why would the pages get "white"?
If I clear the cache in the web browser, the pages sometimes starts working again for the customer.

Could it cause problems like this if the web browser has a proxy configured?

If I access application B directly everything works, but if I access system B via system A (an iframe) sometimes customers has problems with "white" pages.

I have run out of ideas, can anyone lead me in the right direction?
I need some help

```
System B data:
Tomcat 7
Java 6
Struts
```

Comment: inspect your code in firebug and check the "net" console section to see which requests are being made.

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago. The solution was that an exception was thrown in a filter, and the filter returned an empty response to the client - which resulted in seeing a white page in the browser.